# org babel incorrectly output xml like content

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

so I have a test.xml with the following content

```
<root>
  <path>/my/data</path>
  <paths>/global/data</paths>
</root>
```

I then use org-babel to run cat test.xml

I used :results raw, but I tried on all the results types.

the output is very strange. It showed (space included)

```
/my/data</path>
/global/data</paths>
```

putting the input in different file extension. result in the same incorrect output.

What is the cause of this? is it due to limitation of org-babel in some way?

Comment: cannot reproduce on my side with `#+begin_src shell :results raw`

Comment: good to know. Now I can narrow it down to added advise function from third party packages. Thx!